# I'm never gonna win with this beat up shoes. Which Tense does it mean?

Tags: american-english

**I'm never gonna win with this beat up shoes.**
What does it mean?
it means present continues or future tense?

Does it mean like:
"I will never win with this beat up shoes.,"??

Comment: Did you mean **these** beat-up shoes?

Comment: Does it help if you replace "gonna" with "going to"?

Comment: Where did you find this? What is the context? It does not sound like it was written by a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean like: "I will never win.."

Yes.

Correcting the sentence slightly:

> I'm never going to win with these beat up shoes.

"going to" is a construction which indicates future tense. Many publications call this "simple future tense". Others explain:

"Going to is not a tense. It is a special structure that we use to talk about the future." [(englishclub.com)](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_going-to.htm)

Either way, you can interpret "going to" to mean the simple future tense.